# mobileserviceclient loginasync "unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path"

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the test project https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow/

In AuthenticationProvider.cs the function  App.MobileService.LoginAsync throws an exception:  "unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it needed was https for azurewebsite.net link